# MATLAB Function declaration

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to convert the function below to Python, but I am not sure what is going on.

```
function [ray]=create_ray(point1,direction)
ray.direction.x=direction.x;
ray.coefficients.x=(point1.x);
ray.direction.y=direction.y;
ray.coefficients.y=(point1.y);
ray.direction.z=direction.z;
ray.coefficients.z=(point1.z);
```

I know that it returns an array, ray, but what exactly is it doing with direction and coefficients? Could someone please explain to me what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ray` is the return value. The python version will be

```
    def create_ray(point1, direction):
        ...
        return ray
```

where `ray` is `function [`**ray**`]=create_ray(point1,direction)` in the Matlab code.

BTW, the `ray` would be defined by `class` in Python. So the final code can be

```
class Direction(object):
    x, y, z = None, None, None

class Coefficients(object):
    x, y, z = None, None, None

class Ray(object):
    direction = Direction()
    coefficients = Coefficients()

def create_ray(point1, direction):
    ray = Ray()
    ray.direction.x = direction.x;
    ray.coefficients.x = point1.x;
    ray.direction.y = direction.y;
    ray.coefficients.y = point1.y;
    ray.direction.z = direction.z;
    ray.coefficients.z = point1.z;
    return ray
```

Comment: Correct. What about direction and coefficients? Is this a structure array?

Comment: That's all I have. I was just trying to understand what was happening in the function I provided. I am not too familiar with MATLAB, so I was a little confused as to what was going on. Your explanation really helped though.

Comment: OK, I guess... `direction` have scalar values named `x`, `y`, and `z`. And `direction` have coefficients named `x`, `y`, and `z` whose type is `vector` or `matrix` . It's all I guess.

Comment: Thanks, your example helped me to see what was going on.